# Failed Opening Required File

Tags: php

I'm trying to write to console from inside a controller:

```
private function _getHintsFromList($list, $curated = false) {
    set_include_path(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
    require('../../FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
    $firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
    $firephp->fb('Hello World');
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
{"error":true,"message":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\HintController::_getHintsFromList(): Failed opening
 required '..\/..\/FirePHPCore\/FirePHP.class.php' (include_path='\/var\/www\/build\/app\/Http\/lib:
.:\/usr\/share\/php:\/usr\/share\/pear')"}
```

I have checked multiple times and the FirePHPCore folder is 2 folders out of here the controller is located:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: If the file is 4 directories up from where you are currently located, then you need `require_once '../../../../FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php`. You should probably not be calling `require` inside a function. That will load the file every time the function is called, and you'll get fatal errors attempting to redefine classes. At a minimum, it should be `require_once`, but more commonly you would place the require_once outside the function, outside the class definition.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)?

Comment: You should _not_ modify the include_path here at all. Just load the file with its relative path.

Comment: use autoloading for this

Comment: Can you show an example using autoloading?

Comment: While using autoload method is okay, the "core" of current question is not autoload.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you must specify included files in your `index.php` file. The same is actual for `autoloading` function:
index.php:

```
...


set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'app/');

function __autoload($class){    // autoloader
    require_once($class.'.php');
}
...
```

Then you can call your function like the following:

```
class HintController{
    ...
    private function _getHintsFromList($list, $curated = false) {

        $firephp = \FirePHP::getInstance(true);
        $firephp->fb('Hello World');
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_include_path()` is not useful in this case. The execution context (CLI, HTTP server, etc) must be taken in consideration.
Is much more clearer, simpler less and error prone just do something like this:

```
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); 
require $path . '/../../FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php';
```

It should work for your case. Later, you could to consider take a look to `autoload` method and related matters such as [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) / [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/).